# With automator, why does my pdf gets saved twice?

Tags: mac, automator

With automator:
When I create a pdf from images and save it in a location, then create a new folder in that same location the pdf gets copied to the folder, not moved. I don't even need to add a "move files" action. Why is this? It gives me double pdfs.

Is there a way to save the pdf straight into a new folder?

Cheers!

Comment: It is not clear how your Automator workflow looks like. Please describe it in some detail so we can attempt to reproduce the problem.

Comment: my workflow is: create pdf from images →　new folder